# In NetLogo how agents actions are performed?

Tags: netlogo

In my go function I have a few conditions which might be true and then call an action, if more than one condition are true does it mean in one tick agents can do more than one action ? or in another case I have a function that agents have to move to a target and after facing the target agent should find the distance and fd 1 until reaches the target, does it mean it should take n ticks to complete?

```
to move [t]
 face t
 let n distance self t
 repeat n
   [fd 1]
end


to go 
action 1 = > [move]
action 2
action 3 

tick
end
```

I need the agents to do only one task at the time, and I am not sure how to make sure that for example not all the agents have the same target! sorry if these questions are out of context but I am new to Multi-agent modeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question!

First, specific answers:

> if more than one condition are true does it mean in one tick agents can do more than one action ?

Just to be clear, are you talking about a situation like this?

```
to go
  ask turtles [ move ]
  tick
end

to move
  if xcor > 5 [ fd 1 ]
  if ycor > 7 [ rt 15 ]
  if color = red [ bk 2 ]
end
```

If so, then yes, if `xcor > 5`, `ycor > 7`, and `color = red` are all true, the turtle will move forward 1, turn right 15, and move backward 2. The main way to prevent this is by using a sequence of `ifelse`s:

```
to move
  ifelse xcor > 5 [ 
    fd 1
  ] [
    ifelse ycor > 7 [ 
      rt 15 
    ] [
      if color = red [ bk 2 ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

That way, the second condition (`ycor > 7`) will only be looked at if the first condition (`xcor > 5`) is false. Similarly, the third condition will only be looked at if the first two fail.

> I have a function that agents have to move to a target and after facing the target agent should find the distance and fd 1 until reaches the target, does it mean it should take n ticks to complete?

I would recommend taking `n` ticks to complete it. Otherwise, only one turtle will move to its target at a time! However, `repeat n [ fd 1 ]` will make the turtle go forward `n` all at once. In fact, it's the same as `fd n`. The `repeat` block will finish before the turtle is done performing the `move` procedure.

You can edit your `move` function as follows to get it to take `n` ticks:

```
to move [t]
 face t
 fd 1
end
```

Then, just have a condition to look for when the turtle gets to its target (for example, `distance t < 1`) and then do something accordingly.

I recommend just messing around with these various techniques with multiple turtles using them so you can get a feel for the differences.

> I am not sure how to make sure that for example not all the agents have the same target!

This depends quite a bit on context. Supposing there is a `turtles-own` variable called `target` that stores each turtle's target, you could do something like this:

```
to-report get-available-target [ possible-targets ]
  report one-of possible-targets with [ not any? turtles with [ target = myself ] ]
end
```

`get-available-target` will report a random agent from `possible-targets` that is not anyone's target. `one-of` just gets  random agent from an agentset.

> How can I schedule tasks in netlogo, I have conditions and actions but how can I make the agents do one task at the time?

Often this just takes care of itself. For example, say, when an agent is hungry, it should walk over to a food supply and eat. As it's walking over, you don't want it to go off and do anything. However, it will still be hungry, so if you've used an `ifelse`, it will just keep going to the food supply. Thus, your agent stays focused for free! In general, it's best to design your conditions such that they remain in effect until the agent addresses them. You can order them in an `ifelse` chain or something similar to establish the general priority of actions (for instance, if the agent walking to the food supply is threatened by a predator, it should still run away).

If you really want to the agent to do something for several ticks, you'll basically just extend this same idea, but in a more artificial way. For instance, if an agent should walk forward three times, have a `turtles-own` variable set to three. If that variable is greater than zero, the agent walks forward and decreases that variable, and doesn't do anything else.

Comment: Thanks ALOT , that really helps thank you, the reason that I included n in my move function is to make sure if the condition was met and action was chosen, I want to make sure that agent finishes the task in hand before starting another one but it should take a few ticks not all at once, How can I schedule tasks in netlogo, I have conditions and actions but how can I make the agents do one task at the time?

Comment: No problem! Happy to help. I've answered your follow-up question by editing my post.

Answer (score 2):

@Bryan Head already answered your question,  I had the same problem when I started Netlogo and agent based modeling, So I have added a current-task variable and in my Go Procedure I have added a function to check all the conditions and set the task of agents and when the task is completed the variable is set to "" again. This might be useful for your case as well.

```
if current-task = "move" [move] 
if current-task = "A1" [A1] 
if current-task = "..." [...] 
if current-task = "" [select-current-task]
```

Comment: A complete example of this style of coding is State Machine Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library.

Comment: Thanks I just saw that model , its structure is neat and efficient